# Excel formula to calculate a date that a stock level will reach a predetermined safety stock level

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an inventory/stock consumption report that shows:

- stock level (cell E2) and,
- today's date (cell F2)

In cell E3 I have the formula `=E2-$C$7` which is the inventory level less one day's average consumption (cell C7 = 44).

In cell F3 is today's date plus 24hrs (cell C7 = 44).

This is repeated in column E and F until the date equals 02/09/2016 (which is the the customer's contract expiry).

Using this data I can find out the date when the stock level will reach its predetermined safety level of 1080. In this example the stock level reaches 1082 on 16/04/2015. I find the date by finding the nearest stock figure to the safety stock figure using the following array formula ...

```
=VLOOKUP(INDEX(E2:E706,MATCH(MIN(ABS(E2:E706-C2)),ABS(E2:E706-C2),0)),E:F, 2, FALSE)
```

Cell C2 equals the safety stock level (1080).

What I would really like to do is calculate this date in a formula without having to populate the stock figures and date range in columns E and F.
Is there a way for a formula to calculate the date that the stock will reach the safely stock level (or nearest figure to the safety stock) based on a predetermined daily consumption?

```
    A         B         C         D         E         F
1
2                         1080              9838     29/09/2014
3                   02/09/2016              9794     30/09/2014
4                          226              9750     01/10/2014
5                   13/05/2015              9706     02/10/2014
6                         9383              9662     03/10/2014
7                           44              9618     04/10/2014
8                   16/04/2014              9574     05/10/2014
```

Cells C2 to C7 are predetermined values, cell C8 is the array formula above.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us an example? Maybe an image will do - I'm struggling to replicate your results

Comment: I've added a sample in the question, is this any good ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
Current Stock           10000
Average Consumption     44
Safety Stock Level      1080
Days until safety       202
Date of safety          19/04/2015
```

With formulas as follows:

```
Current Stock           10000
Average Consumption     44
Safety Stock Level      1080
Days until safety       =ROUNDDOWN((B1-B3)/B2,0)
Date of safety          =TODAY()+B4
```

Answer (score 0):

Safety stock levels are normally computed in connection with the time taken to replenish stocks and often also with economic order quantities, but with the minimum of `1080` in your example in G2, this should return `16/04/2015`:

```
=F2+(E2-G2)/C7
```

if formatted as a date in the 1900 system.